# Finite loop over a list with repeated parameter

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I am working on an algorithm, and I would like to iterate a function, finitely, over 3 rows of an array. Like, I want to perform the iteration of the function on row1, row2, row3, back to row1, row2, etc.

What I did only stops at after the 3rd row

```
import numpy as np

m, n = 3, 3
A = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
b = [1, 7, 9]

def my_func(x, i):
    pro = x + A_i^T[i,:]
    return pro

rows = 1
rows = [1, 2, 3]
x = np.zeros(n)
for n in range(1000):
   y = my_func(x, rows)
   print(y)
   x = y
   rows += 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate the operation over another iteration

```
for i in range(int(1000/len(rows))): #range(no. of times to iterate row 1, 2 & 3)
    for row in A:
        #put your operations here
```